# How to return value from Special components created by me in another class

Tags: react-native

I'm creating this component _Input.js
[this is image for component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7q9O.jpg)

and i don't know how i can use TextInput Value in another class .

.

Here another class SignInScreen.js
[this is image for another class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STqsq.jpg)

i want to set value <_Input/>       in { username }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass callback functions by props to you `<_input>` component, something like this:

> `<_input changeText={text => this.setState({user: text})}>`

and into you customized component `<_input>` write something like this:

> `<TextInput onChangeText={text => this.props.changeText(text)}`

Comment: From three days I try to solve this problem
Your solution works
But I modified my component from const to class
Now everything is fine thanks to you thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could pass the values in the props of the element:

```
<_input user = {this.state.username} password = {this.state.password}>
```

And the only call them like this in your component:

```
this.props.username
```

```
this.props.props
```

Comment: Here not return value to Parent Class

Comment: i want to use changeText in child and return value to parent class